# Create Upgrade Patch For InstallShield Installer

Tags: installshield

For our latest release, we want our customers to only download an upgrade patch of our applications and instead of uninstall and re-install all the process will be done by upgrader patch but I know nothing about this even after I googled it! Where to start guys? Note that our new release includes database upgrade as well as production code!

We are using .NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010, C# and VB.NET in our software.

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit late to the party but hopefully this post helps anybody else who is looking for this answer.

You can use the 'Patch Design' method to create patches. You can find it in Installation Designer tab under Media.

For this you will need the latest build (msi/exe) and one or more previous build(s). In 'Patch Design' add a new patch configuration. From there you can specify latest version and previous version(s) of your setup file. If you are using Express version then you will need uncompressed build for both latest and previous. If you have Professional version then it can decompress it for you.

After this, just hit Build Patch and it will create a update.exe with only differences between latest and previous builds. It is quite smart in a way where it will only add the binary differences.

Good luck.